# Visual Studio is unable to open include files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, include-path

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'X11/Intrinsic.h': No such file or directory
>
> IntelliSense: cannot open source file "X11/Intrinsic.h"
>
> IntelliSense: cannot open source file "GL/glx.h"

```
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>    /* Display, Window */
#include <GL/glx.h>           /* GLXContext */
```

Comment: The errors are pretty clear to me. And your description should be more meaningful about your question.

Comment: Sorry, you mean, should I type the whole code? or the title is poor I guess.

Comment: So fix your #includes to point to the actual location of the files.

Comment: I have a code and I urgently need to use it, but it keeps giving errors such as this one. I do not have too much knowledge to solve these errors and I really, really need help. Could you help me with that problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compile unix software in msvc. Give up.

You may be able to succeed using mingw or cygwin, but in this case it won't be easy since compiling desktop software (as this seems to be) is always much more complex.